# How to bind an event on the change on Date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is for the calendar:

```
<div class="element-group">
    <label class="element-label with-right-addon">Collection Date</label>
    <div class="element-input-wrap">
        <div class="input-group use-dpicker" data-date="">
            <input class="element-input date-input listen-change" id="drpNewCollectionDateSvc" type="text" > 
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" onclick="$('#drpNewCollectionDateSvc').focus()" style="cursor:pointer"></i></span>                        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is another Dropdown in which I am showing time.

```
<div class="element-group">
    <label class="element-label with-left-addon">Collect After</label>
    <div class="element-input-wrap">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
            <%= Html.SquareDropDownListWithId("drpNewCollectionFutureTimeSvc", (SelectList)ViewData["List_RebookCollectionFutureTimeSvc"], null, "drpNewCollectionFutureTimeSvc", new { id = "drpNewCollectionFutureTimeSvc", @class = "element-input", @Name = "drpNewCollectionFutureTimeSvc", @style = "width:70%; height:18pt; display:none;" })%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 dropdowns, one is for the calendar and another is for the time. I want to make a function in which someone tries to change the Date the dropdown should change.

Answer (score 1):

`drpNewCollectionDateSvc` element is an input. 
So you can handle `onChange` event.

Code is like this:

```
    <input class="element-input date-input listen-change" id="drpNewCollectionDateSvc" type="text" onChange="updateSecond(this.value)">
```

Now you can get value in `updateSecond` function.

```
function updateSecond(value){

}
```